# what's the difference between these facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-canvas

in developing a facebook application, there seem to be three different pages that are involved in the process. Here is a screenshot of page type A, B, and C:

[image: screenshot of three different types of facebook pages]

page type B seems to be very important because it can be linked to from A, and it allows for LIKEs ... how do you create a page B?

Comment: considering how many posts I have seen over the last year on stackoverflow that are in the same vein as this one, why am I being DOWNVOTED and CLOSED ???? ....... are you trolls also auditing the other 100,000 stackoverflow posts to determine if you approve/disapprove??

Comment: y'all better go DOWNVOTE this one also ... and CLOSE it for god's sake before it helps somebody: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822206/profile-app-tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Screen A is facebook page
- Screen B is tab app. (App loaded from within page)
- Screen C is canvas app. (app is loaded separately from page)

The tab app is more tightly related to the page. There is some data that comes in the signed request directly connected to the page. The best example is if the current user is liker or not (the so called fangate is implemented this way).

Steps to create different app types:
When you create an app there are 2 fields sections. Page Tab URL and Canvas URL.

If need **tab app** like screen B (it can be both tab app and canvas app) you should provide the url for Page Tab and additionally go to this link with the correct values:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL

There you can select on which page you want you app to appear as application in favourites, which in turn you can reorder as you feel fit.

example:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=123672637&display=popup&next=http://myapp.myserver.com/

For creating **canvas app** additionally to the Canvas URL you should fill the namespace field.

After that your app can be accessed on https://apps.facebook.com/my_chosen_namespace/

Comment: it seems that some people refer to B as a "Application profile Page" ... but you're suggesting that it is a "tab app page" ....

Comment: App profile page is something totally different and they were removed. source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

Comment: could I ask you to edit your answer, maybe organize your explanation into a bullet point of definitions, something like: **A** - type blah blah _NEWLINE_ **B** - type dah dah _NEWLINE_ **C** - type rah rah

Comment: Done. I think that should be enough. If I add more it will become like a tutorial instead of an answer :)

Comment: Alexander, where did you find out about this step: 
_additionally go to this link with the correct values: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL_ ........... when I am in my app's developer section, and I fill in the Page Tab stuff, there is no message that I must do that step. But indeed it is necessary - it seems to be the only way to assign the Page Tab to a facebook page ... so how did you know about this step please? thanks.

Comment: I don't remember :) I work with facebook apps almost 2 years now and just save important things. Not really trying to remember where from :)

Comment: Here you are https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: Alexander ... I was hoping I could ask you another question about the ADD PAGE TAB dialog ... what is the appropriate YOUR_URL to use: the insecure canvas url, the secure canvas url, the insecure tab page url, the secure tab page url, or something else maybe???? ... The developer's doc doesn't distinguish which should be used or what it will be used for ... thanks, Shannon

Answer (score 0):

The second and third are facbook canvas apps

Comment: No the second is a page tab app, the third is a canvas app

Answer (score -1):

You need to create custom tabs. Use something like https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/